# Swift Dzire Battery Sign remains ON whenever car is started after 9-10 hrs

Tags: battery, starting, alternator

Swift Dzire Battery Sign remains ON in the dashboard lights whenever car is started after 9-10 hrs and **Car doesn't move until the battery sign is gone. Battery Sign usually remains ON for 10-15 seconds.**

This problem doesn't occur with small parking breaks like If I park for 1 hour and start the car again then this problem is not reproduced.

[image: Battery Sign ON]

I went to Maruti Workshop to show my car but as I said that it doesn't occur with small parking breaks , so the problem did not occur in front of Maruti engineers and they checked Battery & Current leakage but no problem was found in that.

There is no fixed pattern to reproduce the problem and it is not occurring Daily .Sometimes it happens daily , sometimes on alternative days. 
Is there anyone who can help with this problem. 
What can be the possible Cause ?

Car is purchased in Oct 2014 and only 7577 kms driven.

Comment: Is it still covered under warranty? You may need to leave it with the mechanic overnight so they can see it for themselves.

Comment: Is the battery light the only on on at this point?  Are you saying you can't select drive while the light is illuminated?

Comment: @ᴘᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 .... Ya i have left it today at the workshop... but the problem is ... it is happening sometimes ...so the mechanics are also confused that what can be the cause and they have told me clearly that if it doesn't happen in front of them then they won't be able to help .

Comment: @HandyHowie... ya only Battery Light is illuminated. and ya I can't drive, if i try to move the car then it doesn't move .... it moves just 1-2 meter. I have added picture in the question.
P.S. This Car is Manual .

Comment: The hand/emergency/parking brake is on in the photo.  Is the brake stopping it moving?

Comment: @HandyHowie - I don't know much about the car at hand, but just recently learned that newer audi's have an electronic/electric parking brake ... wondering if this vehicle might have the same thing and it just doesn't disengage very quickly?

Comment: @HandyHowie ... No I clicked this picture at the parking lot before moving car. Hand brake was removed before trying to move the car.

Comment: When it happens and you cant move the car could you check the battery charge? I'm thinking a faulty charging system that sometimes charges and other times drains the battery and the parking bit might be coincidental so monitoring the battery charge could give a clue to resolve the problem. Also when the light is on and the car wont move what happens if you jumpstart it? For doesnt move you mean driving it not pushing it, right?

Comment: @ErikvanDoren ... Actually I do not have tools to check the battery charge that's why I have left the car with the mechanic today... and Yes with move I mean driving not pushing .... and usually after 10-15 seconds battery lights gets OFF and the car works like normal.. 
And I haven't checked the jumpstart method

Comment: I might suggest checking the alternator diodes...

Comment: @paulster2 Yes, lots of new cars have electric parking brakes now.  Looks like the parking brake was a red herring though.

Comment: Problem got reproduced in front of the mechanic after keeping the car for around 24 hrs, They checked the Alternator and Battery Voltage , Both are absolutely fine. Then they checked **Throttle Body** , there was **Carbon** in it ...so they got it cleaned and I got my car back . I haven't faced the problem since 2 days. I hope I won't face the problem in future .

Comment: @AbhinavDua  Can you answer your question with what was fixed?   :-)

Comment: @DucatiKiller I have posted my reply as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem got reproduced in front of the mechanic after keeping the car for around 24 hrs, They checked the Alternator and Battery Voltage , Both were absolutely fine.

Then they checked **Throttle Body** , there was **Carbon** in it ...so they cleaned the carbon and I got my car back . I haven't faced the problem from that day. I hope I won't face the problem in future